# When I am giving node run.js command then I am getting error I am already npm install but still found error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, solr

`node:util:249
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('superCtor', 'Function', superCtor);
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "superCtor" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
at Object.inherits (node:util:249:11)
at Object. (/home/ansah/Documents/document/server/logs/winston-solr-transport.js:33:6)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object. (/home/ansah/Documents/document/server/logs/log-init.js:10:21) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v19.1.0`

Comment: Please show exactly what you are doing

Comment: var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const pathfinder = require('./server.js');
app.use('/', pathfinder);

// Set port as either specified by command line or 9000
app.set('port', (process.argv[2] || 9000));
// Start server

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Server started: http://localhost:${app.get('port')}/`);
});

Comment: i am start my run.js